# CSS: Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating responsive design, and found up a problem.

I'm using bootstrap 3.0

Summary:

Orange guy has got properties of "col-sm-3" same with blue and yellow, they've got same properties - in overview that is:

```
.orange-blue-yellow {
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```

But problem happened here:

Place with pink stars is blank, and it's messing whole design and grid.

Is there any solution? Probably there is some javascript for that.

[image]

Comment: Please post the complete grid HTML and the relevant CSS

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have rows where you want columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- main row -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- column -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- orange box (row) -->
      <div></div>
      <!-- yellow box (row) -->
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <!-- column -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- blue box (row) -->
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's indeed true. silly me.

wasted 30mins on that, and it was just column dependant.

Thanks Der Flatulator!!!

Comment: This is using Bootstrap 2.x classes, the question states he is using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @cjd82187 My mistake, I haven't used Bootstrap 3 before, but according to the docs I think I have it right this time. Please correct me if I am wrong.